# Is there a way to get puppeteer's waitUntil "networkidle" to only consider XHR (ajax) requests?

Tags: node.js, puppeteer

I am using puppeteer to evaluate the javascript-based HTML of web pages in my test app.

This is the line I am using to make sure all the data is loaded:

```
await page.setRequestInterception(true);
page.on("request", (request) => {
  if (request.resourceType() === "image" || request.resourceType() === "font" || request.resourceType() === "media") {
    console.log("Request intercepted! ", request.url(), request.resourceType());
    request.abort();
  } else {
    request.continue();
  }
});
try {
  await page.goto(url, { waitUntil: ['networkidle0', 'load'], timeout: requestCounterMaxWaitMs });
} catch (e) {

}
```

Is this the best way to wait for **ajax requests** to be completed?

It feels right but I'm not sure if I should use networkidle0, networkidle1, etc?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use [pending-xhr-puppeteer](https://github.com/jtassin/pending-xhr-puppeteer), a lib that expose a promise awaiting that all the pending xhr requests are resolved.

Use it like this :

```
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');
const { PendingXHR } = require('pending-xhr-puppeteer');

const browser = await puppeteer.launch({
  headless: true,
  args,
});

const page = await browser.newPage();
const pendingXHR = new PendingXHR(page);
await page.goto(`http://page-with-xhr`);
// Here all xhr requests are not finished
await pendingXHR.waitForAllXhrFinished();
// Here all xhr requests are finished
```

**DISCLAIMER**: I am the maintener of pending-xhr-puppeteer

Comment: that is sweet pretty awesome! i will try it out when possible and will let you know. our main usecase is javascript evaluated web crawling, which is a very delicate science of "not waiting too long" but "waiting enough" at the same time. does this library help with that do you think?

Comment: Hi @NicholasDiPiazza. I am using it on a react/graphql application to wait its full load. Today, this lib is waiting only the xhr triggered "directly".  The lib should not catch xhr coming from a `setTimeout` or `setInterval`. The lib does not have a feature to wait xhr but "not longer than". For this, you can use `Promise.race` with a setTimeout. I will add an example in the readme for this case.

Comment: This looked really good to start with , but it doesn't cope very well with multiple pages. If I add to the page at the start , then it doesn't seem to work properly ( there are xhr requests "hanging around" .  If I only add it in a particular function , then we hit the maxlisteners errors and memory leaks. There needs to be an easy way to "remove" the listeners after use.

Comment: You're right, I do not flush listener on page change. I've just created a issue with it. Thx

Answer (score 6):

XHR by their nature can appear later in the app. Any `networkidle0` will not help you if app sends XHR after for example 1 second and you want to wait for it. I think if you want to do this "properly" you should know what requests you are waiting for and `await` for them.

Here is an example with XHRs occurred later in the app and it wait for all of them:

```
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');

const html = `
<html>
  <body>
    <script>
      setTimeout(() => {
        fetch('https://swapi.co/api/people/1/');
      }, 1000);

      setTimeout(() => {
        fetch('https://www.metaweather.com/api/location/search/?query=san');
      }, 2000);

      setTimeout(() => {
        fetch('https://api.fda.gov/drug/event.json?limit=1');
      }, 3000);
    </script>
  </body>
</html>`;

// you can listen to part of the request
// in this example I'm waiting for all of them
const requests = [
    'https://swapi.co/api/people/1/',
    'https://www.metaweather.com/api/location/search/?query=san',
    'https://api.fda.gov/drug/event.json?limit=1'
];

const waitForRequests = (page, names) => {
  const requestsList = [...names];
  return new Promise(resolve =>
     page.on('request', request => {
       if (request.resourceType() === "xhr") {
         // check if request is in observed list
         const index = requestsList.indexOf(request.url());
         if (index > -1) {
           requestsList.splice(index, 1);
         }

         // if all request are fulfilled
         if (!requestsList.length) {
           resolve();
         }
       }
       request.continue();
     })
  );
};


(async () => {
  const browser = await puppeteer.launch();
  const page = await browser.newPage();
  await page.setRequestInterception(true);

  // register page.on('request') observables
  const observedRequests = waitForRequests(page, requests);

  // await is ignored here because you want to only consider XHR (ajax) 
  // but it's not necessary
  page.goto(`data:text/html,${html}`);

  console.log('before xhr');
  // await for all observed requests
  await observedRequests;
  console.log('after all xhr');
  await browser.close();
})();
```

Comment: So, this is works by defining requests URL. but how about arbitrary network requests? like if the url contains random uuid generated when a resource is created?

Comment: @otong it's entirely ad-hoc, so you'd replace `requestsList.indexOf(request.url());` with whatever pattern logic defines the resource you expect. For example, if you had a uuid of 10 alphanumeric characters, you might use something like `/^http:\/\/www.example.com\/[a-zA-Z\d]{10}$/.test(request.url())` and keep a data structure/flag for whether it'd been previously requested (if that matters to your use case).

Comment: Adding to this answer, Puppeteer also offers [`page.waitForResponse`](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/blob/v1.17.0/docs/api.md#pagewaitforresponseurlorpredicate-options) to wait for a specific response to resolve without necessarily having to promisify `page.on("request", ...)`, although it's good to see multiple approaches.

Comment: Also, it's a good idea to do `page.once("request", ...)` in this case rather than `page.on("request", ...)` so the handler is removed after it fires once.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with the sentiment in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49541580/6243352) that waiting for *all* network activity to cease ("all the data is loaded") is a rather ambiguous concept that is entirely dependent on the behavior of the website you're scraping.

Options for detecting responses include waiting a fixed duration, a fixed duration after network traffic idles, for a specific response (or set of responses), for an element to appear on the page, for a predicate to return true, etc, all of which [Puppeteer supports](https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/blob/main/docs/api.md).

With this in mind, the most typical scenario is that you're waiting for some particular response or set of responses from known (or partially-known, using some pattern or prefix) resource URL(s) that will deliver a payload you want to read and/or trigger a DOM interaction you need to detect. Puppeteer offers [`page.waitForResponse`](https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/blob/v1.17.0/docs/api.md#pagewaitforresponseurlorpredicate-options) for doing just this.

Here's an example, building on an [existing answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49541580/6243352) (and showing how to retrieve the data from the responses while we're at it):

```
const puppeteer = require("puppeteer");

const html = `
<html>
  <body>
    <script>
      setTimeout(() => {
        fetch("http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users/1");
      }, 1000);
      setTimeout(() => {
        fetch("http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users/2");
      }, 2000);
      setTimeout(() => {
        fetch("http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users/3");
      }, 3000);
      setTimeout(() => {
        // fetch something irrelevant to us
        fetch("http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users/4");
      }, 0);
    </script>
  </body>
</html>`;

(async () => {
  const browser = await puppeteer.launch();
  const [page] = await browser.pages();
  await page.setContent(html);
  const expectedUrls = [
    "http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users/1",
    "http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users/2",
    "http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users/3",
  ];

  try {
    const responses = await Promise.all(expectedUrls.map(url =>
      page.waitForResponse(
        response => response.url() === url, 
        {timeout: 5000}
      )
    ));
    const data = await Promise.all(
      responses.map(response => response.json())
    );
    console.log(data);
  }
  catch (err) {
    console.error(err);
  }

  await browser.close();
})()
```