# Resolve promise on specific event at puppeteer

Tags: javascript, node.js, ajax, puppeteer

How can I continue with my puppeteer code after a specific event happens? in a sort of synchronous way. For example, I have the following 'request' event code:

```
await page.on('request', request => {
  if (request.resourceType() === 'xhr'){
    //do something
  }
});
```

My puppeteer code depends from an AJAX call response at a specific page to fill a form. So I guess I have to make the request event function in a way that it resolves a promise when the conditions are met to use it as a reference later in the code but I would appreciate some guidance on the topic since I'm not very familiar with asynchronous code nor promises or puppeteer. Thanks!

Comment: `sort of synchronous way` - not even sort of synchronous is possible with something that depends on an event, specific or otherwise ... this code snippet `await page.on` ... does `page.on` return a promise? (hint: not likely - so that won't help at all)

Comment: I would strongly advise against using Promises with event handlers anyway - why not continue with your code where you have `//do something`? but maybe this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/sxe53Lam/) will give you some ideas

Comment: Because there are multiple requests that fire the event handler, and since my app depends on a specific AJAX request to fill a form and accomplish its main task, I need a way to let the code know when that specific request has been completed in order to continue, that's why I thought that a promise that can be referenced later in the code would be ideal. I don't see a reason why not to use this approach, would you please give me a further explanation?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can wrap up `page.on('request')` in Promise before you enter the page and wait for this promise to be resolved like this:

```
const observedXhr = new Promise(resolve =>
  page.on('request', request => {
    if (request.resourceType() === "xhr") {
      resolve();
    }
    request.continue();
  })
);

// later in the code

await observedXhr;

// rest of the program after xhr is compleated
```

Here is full example:

```
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');

const html = `
<html>
  <body>
    <script>
      fetch('https://swapi.co/api/people/1/');
    </script>
  </body>
</html>`;

(async () => {
  const browser = await puppeteer.launch();
  const page = await browser.newPage();
  await page.setRequestInterception(true);

  const observedXhr = new Promise(resolve =>
    page.on('request', request => {
      if (request.resourceType() === "xhr") {
        resolve();
      }
      request.continue();
    })
  );

  await page.goto(`data:text/html,${html}`);

  console.log('before xhr');

  // await for resolved promise
  await observedXhr;

  console.log('after xhr');
  await browser.close();
})();
```

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49538478/3708596) question extends yours - it will be valuable for you.

Comment: Perfect! this is what I thought. Thanks a lot :)